# Only one of two textboxes is required (custom validator)

Tags: c#, asp.net

**Explanation:** I have two text boxes, it is optional for the users to fill in both, but is mandatory that the user fills in at least one of them.

**Expected result:** error message shown 
**Unexpected results:** the error message isn't shown

HTML:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TB1" runat="server" /> 
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CV1" ControlToValidate="TB1" runat="server" OnServerValidate="blabla" ErrorMessage="one of two required" />
<asp:TextBox ID="TB2" runat="server" />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CV2" ControlToValidate="TB2" runat="server" OnServerValidate="blabla" ErrorMessage="they cant both be blank" />
```

C#:

```
protected void blabla(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
    if (TB1.Text.Length == 0 && TB2.Text.Length == 0)
        e.IsValid = false; 
    else
        e.IsValid = true; 
}
```

Please can you help explain why isn't this working guys?

Comment: what u actully want.explain in brief..................??????

Comment: What isn't working? Is the blabla event being raised? Are you getting an exception? Is it not performing as you would expect?

Comment: Only one, or at least one? Also, explain what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Sorry guys for not being clear enough, I've updated the post.

Comment: What is the unexpected result?

Comment: && means `and` as in if both lengths are 0 then its not valid..

Comment: @Nolonar one or the other, it is not firing the validator.

Comment: I tried replacing 
`TB1.Text.Length == 0` with `string.IsNullOrEmpty(TB1.Text.Trim())` and it still doesn't work. Any ideas guys?

Comment: @Belogix, the blabla event isn't even being raised.

Comment: think it should be the condition should be e.IsValid = TB1.Text.Length>0 || TB2.Text.Length>0

Comment: Also see a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651155/asp-net-customvalidator-never-fires-onservervalidate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need one `CustomValidator` for both. It's the only validator where you can omit the `ControlToValidate` for cases like this.

aspx:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TB1" runat="server" /> 
<asp:TextBox ID="TB2" runat="server" />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CV1"runat="server" 
    OnServerValidate="ServerValidation" 
    ErrorMessage="one of two required" />
```

codebehind:

```
protected void ServerValidation(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    args.IsValid = TB1.Text.Trim().Length > 0 || TB2.Text.Trim().Length > 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 Good answer as always Tim. You can do client side validation too.

Answer (score 1):

`&&` means `and` as in if both lengths are 0 then its not valid, try

```
bool b = false;
if (TB1.Text.Length != 0)
b = true;

if (TB2.Text.Length != 0)
b = true;

e.IsValid = b;
```

Comment: Note: I prefer Tim's answer, although Im not a fan of really long or statements so would prefer this if there were to be extra textboxes to compare with

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
protected void blabla(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(TB1.Text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(TB2.Text))
        e.IsValid = false;
    else
        e.IsValid = true;
}
```

Also using `ValidationGroup` property can be useful:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TB1" runat="server" /> 
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CV1" ControlToValidate="TB1" runat="server" OnServerValidate="blabla" ErrorMessage="one of two required" validationgroup="validationGroup" />
<asp:TextBox ID="TB2" runat="server" />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CV2" ControlToValidate="TB2" runat="server" OnServerValidate="blabla" ErrorMessage="they cant both be blank" validationgroup="validationGroup" />

<asp:button id="ValidateButton" text="Validate" validationgroup="validationGroup" runat="server"/>
```

Comment: It is more easily solved with Tim's approach of using only a single customvalidator, but thank you so much for your reply.